# eclipse and easy eclipse interface differentiation, for casual java programmers

Tags: eclipse

what is the difference between the easy eclipse interface and regular eclipse?
any other specifics that i should consider when picking between the 2?

Answer (score 1):

It depends when you consider the versions of Eclipse you want to use.

Easy Eclipse is just a [pre-packaged Eclipse with some plugins](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/index.html).
But it is at most in [Eclipse3.4](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/news/index.html).

That means, compared to Eclipse3.5 (Galileo) or 3.6 (Helios), the differences are actually in the "New and Noteworthy" sections of those two more recent distros.

- [Eclipse 3.5 New and Noteworthy](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-all.html)
- [Eclipse 3.6 New and Noteworthy](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news.html)